# Attached property binding proxy

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, attached-properties

I have this binding in xaml:

```
<Popup IsOpen="{Binding Path=(local:ListViewBehavior.IsColumnHeaderClicked),
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,  AncestorType=GridViewColumnHeader}}" ...
```

`Popup` is located inside `GridViewColumn.Header`.

`ListViewBehavior.IsColumnHeaderClicked` is a simple `bool` attached property:

```
public static bool GetIsColumnHeaderClicked(DependencyObject obj) => (bool)obj.GetValue(IsColumnHeaderClickedProperty);
public static void SetIsColumnHeaderClicked(DependencyObject obj, bool value) => obj.SetValue(IsColumnHeaderClickedProperty, value);
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsColumnHeaderClickedProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsColumnHeaderClicked", typeof(bool), typeof(ListViewBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(false));
```

Its value is set by some code behind:

```
void listView_ColumnClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var column = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;
    SetIsColumnHeaderClicked(column, !GetIsColumnHeaderClicked(column)); // toggle
}
```

Idea is to show popup when `GridViewColumnHeader` is clicked. Everything so far is working.

Question: how bind this attached property to `IsPopupOpen` property in my ViewModel?

I was thinking about some kind of proxy which is used to bind to attached property and to ViewModel property at same time. Or perhaps I should bind to `IsOpen` again? Bind twice? Is this even possible?

Comment: Why dont you use Two way Binding? It will set the property in your VM automatically.

Comment: @FromStuckToFlow, it's `TwoWay` already (closing popup will set value to `false`). ViewModel property is not yet bound to attached property, I don't know where and how to do it.

Comment: The way i do it , i have Binder Class that i use to hold all properties i want to bind in my UI.In the ViewModel i use the Binder and for example if i wanna see if checkbox is checked - binder.Property = true etc...

Comment: Could you add the part of the view with the ListView and the event whose listView_ColumnClicked handler is linked to ?

Comment: @Arhiman, it's `listView.AddHandler(GridViewColumnHeader.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(listView_ColumnClicked))` in attached behavior. The idea is to use attached behavior to subscribe listView to `GridViewColumnHeader.ClickEvent` (attached event?), in this event for clicked column value of attached property will be changed and then I can bind to that attached property in the View (to show popup). And my problem is to also pass this value to ViewModel somehow. Actually, I could use data triggers of popup (when it's shown/hidden) to bind to it... "Rubber duck" is working, let me try it.

Comment: [Doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36080405/1997232) though.