# View property - bind twice

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

Is it possible to bind the same property of the control more than once?

To example:

```
<Popup IsOpen="{Binding Path=(local:ListViewBehavior.IsColumnHeaderClicked),
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,  AncestorType=GridViewColumnHeader}}" ...
```

As you can see `Popup.IsOpen` is bound to attached property. I'd like to bind it to ViewModel `IsPopupOpened`, but have no idea how.

---

Trying @Arhiman answer without much success:

```
<Popup.IsOpen>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{local:MultiBindingConverter}">
        <Binding Path="(local:ListViewBehavior.IsColumnHeaderClicked)"
                 RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=GridViewColumnHeader}" />
        <Binding Path="DataContext.IsPopupId"
                 RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}" />
    </MultiBinding>
</Popup.IsOpen>
```

*Naive* converter logic:

```
public class MultiBindingConverter : MarkupExtension, IMultiValueConverter
{
    public MultiBindingConverter() { }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => this;

    object[] _old;

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (_old == null)
            _old = values.ToArray();
        // check if one of values is changed - that change is a new value
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            if (values[i] != _old[i])
            {
                _old = values.ToArray();
                return values[i];
            }
        return values[0];
    }

    // replicate current value
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
        Enumerable.Repeat(value, targetTypes.Length).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use a MultiBinding with a converter to implement the logic you'd like.

```
<Popup.IsOpen>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource openLogicConverter}">
        <Binding Path="MyAttachedProperty" ... />
        <Binding Path="IsPopupOpened" />
    </MultiBinding>
</Popup.IsOpen>
```

I'd usually put this logic in the ViewModel, but as it is an AttachedProperty, something directly in the View seems more appropriate to me.

Comment: I couldn't make it working yet. Idea is clear, but the problem is a converter logic. Typically you have property in ViewModel and then multiple controls bound to it. When either of controls or ViewModel itself changes the property - all controls gets updated. I want something mirrored: single control bound to multiple properties. When either property is change - all other properties and control should be updated. Can you show how `openLogicConverter` would looks like to *pass* values between bindings? See edit.

Comment: I should rather try to create mcve for scenario I describe and ask another question.

Comment: It seems I didn't understand your question. I might need some clarifying actually, like what are the differents actors in the scenario, what are the properties, which affects what, and such.
Also, is it possible to centralize all these properties to the one in the ViewModel, instead of using a behavior ? This ViewModel property who then fits the role of the master, in a master-slave like paradigm. Depends if this ListView is possible to bind to the ViewModel.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36064419/1997232). I simplified the problem to an easy repro.

Comment: I'm not sure I did quite get it so I'll just add this comment, sorry if it's still not the right answer.
I'd have an instance of a ColumnHeaderViewModel or something, that is passed to both the ViewModel used in the PopUp and the one used in the ListView. This ColumnHeaderVM would be the one that possess the property you need (previously in the AttachedProperty and the ViewModel of your Popup). This property from CHVM would also replace your AttachedProperty and would be used for the IsOpen binding.

Comment: There is no `ColumnHeaderVM`. View has `ListView` with columns (defined in xaml). I have attached property triggered by some [black magic](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36041383/1997232) when user click column header. Attached property can be used only in the view (it's bound to `Popup.IsOpen` as you can see, I wouldn't be able to access column header in the ViewModel). And my problem only to pass this value from the View to ViewModel somehow.