# Is it possible to use trigger setter to change ViewModel property?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I am opening Popup using `IsOpen` bound to some *hard to reach* attached property. All I want is to somehow pass `IsOpen` value to ViewModel.

Trying to use setter for this:

```
<Popup StaysOpen="False"
       IsOpen="{Binding Path=(local:ListViewBehavior.IsColumnHeaderClicked), RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=GridViewColumnHeader}}">
    <Popup.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Popup">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsOpen" Value="True">
                    <!-- this is not possible -->
                    <Setter Property="{Binding IsPopupOpened ...}" Value="True" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Popup.Style>
</Popup>
```

Gives:

> A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Property' property of type 'Setter'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

Is there a way to pass `IsOpen` value (which is already bound to something else in the View) to ViewModel?

Comment: What about `<Style TargetType="Popup"><Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="{Binding VMProperty}"></Style>`

Comment: He already has a Binding to the IsOpen Property...

Comment: @FrerkMorrin Wow, sorry. I need more sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could created an attached Property, which is set by eventhandlers to the Opened and Closed Events of the Popup. That can be bind to the IsPopupOpen Property of your ViewModel by OneWayToSource Binding.
I'm also not quite sure if there is an easier Solution, but this is a kind of "Workaround" what I would do, in case that no-one provides a better solution here.